# Tired of the Apple Mail Client Woosh sound on mail send

Tags: mail.app, macos

I am using Macbook pro 13inch 2015 model. Using OSX Sierra.

Every time I send a mail with the apple mail client is makes a woosh sound. In order to suppress this sound I have done the following things

1. Go into settings -> notifications and switch off the notification sounds for mail client.

[image]

2. Disable User Interface sound effects in settings -> sound.

[image]

However still when I send a mail it makes a stupid woooosh sound.

Comment: Pro Tip: If you hit cmd/shift/4 for a screen shot, **then** tap the space bar, you can click in the window you want to screenshot & it will save with a nice little drop shadow too. Lovely for SE illustrations etc :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to **Mail's** Preferences. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Mail > Preferences > General tab

Deselect the

> Play sounds for other mail actions

checkbox.

[image: Checkbox location in Mail preferences]

Comment: What does this affect besides the 'sent sound'?