# How to quiet or mute iOS 12 Mail Send sound?

Tags: ios, settings, sound-volume

Same as [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273886/tired-of-the-apple-mail-client-woosh-sound-on-mail-send), but iOS has changed.

The whoosh sound when Mail app sends a message is too loud. I've tried the volume down button while using Mail but it didn't change. I muted the receive notification sound already.

How do I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going into `Settings` then `Sounds & Haptics`, then scroll down to `Sent Mail` and select `None`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. There are so many different places in iOS that might have volume controls. Settings > Notifications, Settings > Sounds & Haptics, Settings > (App Name), and of course in the app itself.